# Custom ServiceHostFactory fails on Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2012, iis

I am experiencing a very weird error with a WCF service on a Windows 2012 Server R2 Standard with IIS Version 8.5.9600.16384. I have implemented a Custom ServiceHostFactory as you can see in the code below. I used Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 to compile the code and publish it on my local machine. 
The service works fine locally. But when I try to deploy the same code (just copy all the files from my machine to the server) I get an HttpCompileException exception. The Application Pool is setup with .NET Version v4.0.30319 and the Managed pipeline mode is “Integrated” in both machines, mine and the server. 
I cannot understand why the same code works on my machine and not on the server. The only difference between the two is the operating system and IIS version. My machine runs Windows 7 and IIS 7.

MyService.svc contains the following:

```
<%@ServiceHost
    Language="C#"
    Debug="false"
    Service="MyService"
    Factory="CustomServiceHostFactory"%>
```

Here is my implementation of CustomServiceHostFactory that extends UnityServiceHostFactory.

```
public class CustomServiceHostFactory : UnityServiceHostFactory
  {
      protected override void InitializeLocalDependencies(IUnityContainer container)
      {
          var initializer = new ContainerInitializer();
          initializer.Initialize(container);
      //do stuff
      }
  }
```

Here is my implementation of UnityServiceHostFactory  that extends System.ServiceMode.Activation.ServiceHostFactory

```
public class UnityServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
   {
       private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

       public UnityServiceHostFactory()
       {
           _container = new UnityContainer(); 
          //do stuff    
       }
```

Here is the exception:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpCompileException 
    Exception message: The CLR Type 'CustomServiceHostFactory' could not be loaded during service compilation. Verify that this type is either defined in a source file located in the application's \\App_Code directory, contained in a compiled assembly located in the application's \\bin directory, or present in an assembly installed in the Global Assembly Cache. Note that the type name is case-sensitive and that the directories such as \\App_Code and \\bin must be located in the application's root directory and cannot be nested in subdirectories.
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
The CLR Type ‘CustomServiceHostFactory' could not be loaded during service compilation. Verify that this type is either defined in a source file located in the application's \\App_Code directory, contained in a compiled assembly located in the application's \\bin directory, or present in an assembly installed in the Global Assembly Cache. Note that the type name is case-sensitive and that the directories such as \\App_Code and \\bin must be located in the application's root directory and cannot be nested in subdirectories.
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Below you will find a list of the .NET versions and tools I have installed on my Windows Server 2012. My project is compiled with .NET Framework 4.5.

Features:

- **NET Framework 3.5 Features**
- Net Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
- HTTP Activation
- **NET Framework 4.5 Featues**
- .Net Framework 4.5 ASP.NET 4.5
- WCF Services
- HTTP Activation
- Name Pipe Actication
- TCP Actication
  -TCP Port Sharing

Comment: It seems like a .NET framework problem since it saying CLR type couldn't be loading , check what .NET Version you have on your server

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

- Add a reference to Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll in your project.

My project was missing a reference to Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll. My local machine must have that dll file somewhere else so that the service worked fine locally. However the server did not have it. So it reacted by giving me a very unhelpful message to tell me I was missing a reference.